# How to turn on/off  boot messages when Ubuntu starts?

Tags: kernel, startup

Is there a way to easily turn on/off showing the boot messages (loading the services) when Ubuntu starts? My machine uses WUBI for boot-up.

The reason I am asking is to figure out if the reason for the lockups is caused by events which happen a boot-up. I see messages which are cleared out before I can read them. If there is a place where all errors are logged, even when the booting file system is read, I would like to know so I can read them instead.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/var/log/syslog.1` contains the system log of the earlier boot.

Comment: I found the syslog.1 file in /var/log/syslog.1 . It does not have the same information which I thought I read. Could be the wrong file or not clear for a lay person or I did not read enough of the error correctly. I think it had to do with NTFS, but it was clear off the screen before I could read it.

Comment: By the way, there is no /var/syslog directory. And, the freezes happens over a day apart but less than a week.

Comment: oops /var/log/syslog.1 is the correct file!

Comment: The info at syslog.1 does not seem to help. How do I do change the showing the boot messages on a WUBI for boot-up?

Comment: Is there a way to show the boot messages with WUBI?